# Convertir primera letra de cada palabra en mayuscula

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta en la que quisiera que el campo `PUESTO` me devolviera su valor Capitalizado, quiero decir la primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula y el resto en minúscula

La consulta la tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
select 
        DEPTO,
        SUBSTRING(UPPER(PUESTO),1,1) + SUBSTRING(LOWER(PUESTO),2,50),
    from Personal
```

Esta consulta me devuelve el valor pero con la primera letra de toda la cadena en mayúscula, quisiera que fuera la primera letra de cada palabra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ese tipo de *case* se llama, en inglés, **Proper Case** o **Title Case**.

Puedes escribir una función para realizar la tarea, por ejemplo, en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230177/255257) de StackOverflow en Inglés, encontré esta función que hace el trabajo sucio:

```
create function ProperCase(@Text as varchar(8000))
returns varchar(8000)
as
begin
  declare @Reset bit;
  declare @Ret varchar(8000);
  declare @i int;
  declare @c char(1);

  if @Text is null
    return null;

  select @Reset = 1, @i = 1, @Ret = '';

  while (@i <= len(@Text))
    select @c = substring(@Text, @i, 1),
      @Ret = @Ret + case when @Reset = 1 then UPPER(@c) else LOWER(@c) end,
      @Reset = case when @c like '[a-zA-Z]' then 0 else 1 end,
      @i = @i + 1
  return @Ret
end
```

Una vez creada la función, utilizala en tu sentencia select así:

```
select depto, dbo.ProperCase(puesto) as puesto
  from Personal;
```

Una sugerencia que me gustaría darte es que, en lugar de llamar a esta función todo el tiempo, actualices la información que se encuentra en la tabla, por ejemplo:

```
update personal
   set puesto = dbo.ProperCase(puesto);
```

Claro que, luego, debes hacer esto cada vez que ingrese/actualice un nuevo registro, pero hará que tu base de datos sea más eficiente, ya que el número de veces que se hace un `select` suele ser mayor a las veces que se inserta/actualiza este tipo de registros.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, aquí me surge una duda puedo hacer uso de dicha función en un Store Procedure ?

Comment: Si claro, si se puede.

Comment: Nuevamente gracias por tu respuesta, ya le di validación a la misma, solo me queda una ultima duda es posible excluir ciertas palabras de dicha función?, si te interesa [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434292/como-excluir-ciertas-cadenas-de-caracteres-de-una-funci%c3%b3n) lo comente en una pregunta

Comment: @jachguate Muy buena la función, yo necesito algo similar pero que me deje los espacio que tiene cada palabra intente agregando una condición pero no me funciono.

Comment: @Juanzu, no puedo imaginarme que dificultad tienes, pero si lo has intentado y no lo consigues, podrías publicar una pregunta al respecto.