# Como excluir ciertas cadenas de caracteres de una función

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera excluir algunas cadenas de caracteres en especifico de una función, la siguiente función me permite convertir la primera letra de cada palabra en Mayúscula y las demás en Minúscula.

```
create function ProperCase(@Text as varchar(8000))
returns varchar(8000)
as
begin
  declare @Reset bit;
  declare @Ret varchar(8000);
  declare @i int;
  declare @c char(1);

  if @Text is null
    return null;

  select @Reset = 1, @i = 1, @Ret = '';

  while (@i <= len(@Text))
    select @c = substring(@Text, @i, 1),
      @Ret = @Ret + case when @Reset = 1 then UPPER(@c) else LOWER(@c) end,
      @Reset = case when @c like '[a-zA-Z]' then 0 else 1 end,
      @i = @i + 1
  return @Ret
end
```

La función la tome de StackOverflow en Inglés, [aquí la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230138/sql-server-make-all-upper-case-to-proper-case-title-case/230177#230177)

Para hacer uso de dicha función lo ejecuto en la siguiente consulta:

```
select depto, dbo.ProperCase(puesto) as puesto
  from Personal;
```

La anterior función me convierte la cadena de caracteres a texto Capitalizado de la siguiente manera

```
Ejemplo De Stackoverflow
```

Pero quisiera excluir de esta función algunas palabras conectores como lo son: **De, Por,**, ya que no deseo que estas palabras conectores no cambie su primera letra a mayúscula, quiero que mi texto quede de la siguiente manera:

```
Ejemplo de Stackoverflow
```

Es posible excluir de la anterior función estas palabras conectores o hay otra forma de pasar capitalizar un texto sin tener en cuenta los conectores que menciono anteriormente.

Answer (score 0):

Por la forma en la que está escrita la función, resulta bastante complejo *excluir* algunas cadenas.

Sin embargo, lo que puedes hacer es dejar que la función trabaje como lo viene haciendo y  **sustituir** las cadenas que te interesan, al final de la misma, para lo que puedes valerte de la función [replace()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)

Por ejemplo, para sustituir las cadenas que mencionas en la pregunta, puedes hacer lo siguiente, justo antes de retornar el valor:

```
  set @Ret = Replace(@Ret, ' De ', ' de ');
  set @Ret = Replace(@Ret, ' Por ', ' por ');
  return @Ret
end
```

Si te fijas bien, he tenido el cuidado de sustituir las cadenas solo cuando están rodeadas de espacios, lo que evita que se sustituyan cuando están dentro de otra palabra o al inicio de la cadena, donde seguramente si quieres que inicie con mayúscula.

Comment: Tu idea es buena, pero te olvidas de que las cadenas pueden tener signos de puntuación y no solo espacios. Estoy buscando una alternativa a eso.

Answer (score 0):

Dejo una versión alternativa a la función, ya que como te han dicho, la función que tienes no se puede modificar de forma sencilla para prevenir que ciertas palabras reciban mayúscula inicial.

Esta función es una función de tabla en línea y funciona un poco distinto a como lo haría una función de valor escalar.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ProperCase(
    @pString VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Tabla de Números" en línea produce valores de 0 hasta 10,000...
     -- suficiente para manejar VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1 AS (
              SELECT N 
              FROM(VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(N)
             ),                          --10E+1 or 10 filas
       E2 AS (SELECT a.N FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 filas
       E4 AS (SELECT a.N FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 filas máximas
 cteTally AS (--==== Esto genera una "base cero" y limita el número de filas antes de generarlas
                  -- Sirve para mejorar rendimiento y prevenir errores de valores extras.
              SELECT N = 0 
              UNION ALL
              SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
             ),
 cteStart AS (--==== Esto regresa N+1 (el inicio de cada palabra para no pasar por cada letra)
              SELECT N1 = t.N+1
                FROM cteTally t
               WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) NOT LIKE '[A-Z]' OR t.N = 0) 
             ),
 cteSplit AS (
              --===== Dividimos la cadena en palabras. El combo ISNULL/NULLIF sirve para manejar el la última palabra
                   -- También cambiamos todo a minúsculas
               SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
                      Item = LOWER( SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1)),1)-s.N1,8000)))
                 FROM cteStart s
       )
SELECT Cadena =( SELECT CASE WHEN Item IN ( 'de', 'con', 'por', 'el') AND ItemNumber > 1 THEN Item -- Aquí podemos incluir las palabrar a excluir
                             ELSE STUFF( Item, 1, 1, UPPER(LEFT( Item, 1))) END -- Aquí cambiamos la primer letra minúscula por mayúscula.
                        FROM cteSplit
                        ORDER BY ItemNumber -- Preservamos el orden
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') -- Con esta instrucción volvemos a unir la cadena.
;
```

Para poder utilizarla, tu código tendría que cambiar a algo similar a esto.

```
SELECT depto, 
       ppc.Cadena as puesto
  FROM Personal
CROSS APPLY dbo.ProperCase(puesto) ppc;
```

El código está lleno de comentarios, pero puedo agregar más detalle a la respuesta para explicar algo de ser necesario.

Comment: Que diferencia existe entre la función de tabla en línea y una función de valor escalar como la que estoy usando ?

Comment: Existen muchas diferencias. La más obvia es la forma en que se llaman, ya que requieren de la instrucción `APPLY`. Otra diferencia es que se integran directamente a la consulta, pudiendo generar mejores planes de ejecución y mejor rendimiento.